# Filter data with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where I have the following data. Each row represents a word appearing in each episode of a TV series. If a word appears 3 times in an episode, the pandas dataframe has 3 rows. Now I need to filter a list of words such that I should only get only words which appear more than or equal to 2 times. I can do this by `groupby`, but if a word appears 2 (or say 3,4 or 5) times, I need two (3, 4 or 5) rows for it.

By groupby, I will only get the unique entry and count, but I need the entry to repeat as many times as it appears in the dialogue. Is there a one-liner to do this?

```
       dialogue  episode
0         music        1
1   corrections        1
2       somnath        1
3         yadav        5
4          join        2
5     instagram        1
6          wind        2
7         music        1
8    whimpering        2
9         music        1
10         wind        3
```

SO here I should ideally get,

```
   dialogue  episode
0     music        1
6      wind        2
7     music        1
9     music        1
10     wind        3
```

As these are the only 2 words that appear more than or equal to 2 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use groupby's [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
In [11]: df.groupby("dialogue").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
Out[11]:
   dialogue  episode
0     music        1
6      wind        2
7     music        1
9     music        1
10     wind        3
```

Comment: i like this solution more

Answer (score 4):

**Answer for the updated question:**

```
In [208]: df.groupby('dialogue')['episode'].transform('size') >= 3
Out[208]:
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9      True
10    False
dtype: bool

In [209]: df[df.groupby('dialogue')['episode'].transform('size') >= 3]
Out[209]:
  dialogue  episode
0    music        1
7    music        1
9    music        1
```

**Answer for the original question:**

you can use [duplicated()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method:

```
In [202]: df[df.duplicated(subset=['dialogue'], keep=False)]
Out[202]:
   dialogue  episode
0     music        1
6      wind        2
7     music        1
9     music        1
10     wind        3
```

if you want to sort the result:

```
In [203]: df[df.duplicated(subset=['dialogue'], keep=False)].sort_values('dialogue')
Out[203]:
   dialogue  episode
0     music        1
7     music        1
9     music        1
6      wind        2
10     wind        3
```

Comment: I have a broader concern in my mind, If I need to filter by the criteria of a word appearing more than 5 (or 7, 8 or 9) times, then what should be the change

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `value_counts`

```
vc = df.dialogue.value_counts() >= 2
vc = vc[vc]
df[df.dialogue.isin(vc.index)]
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

keep in mind, this is completely over the top.  however, i'm sharpening up my timing skills.

**code**

```
from timeit import timeit

def pirsquared(df):
    vc = df.dialogue.value_counts() > 1
    vc = vc[vc]
    return df[df.dialogue.isin(vc.index)]

def maxu(df):
    return df[df.groupby('dialogue')['episode'].transform('size') > 1]

def andyhayden(df):
    return df.groupby("dialogue").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

rows = ['pirsquared', 'maxu', 'andyhayden']
cols = ['OP_Given', '10000_3_letters']

summary = pd.DataFrame([], rows, cols)
iterations = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'dialogue': {0: 'music', 1: 'corrections', 2: 'somnath', 3: 'yadav', 4: 'join', 5: 'instagram', 6: 'wind', 7: 'music', 8: 'whimpering', 9: 'music', 10: 'wind'}, 'episode': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 5, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 3}})

summary.loc['pirsquared', 'OP_Given'] = timeit(lambda: pirsquared(df), number=iterations)
summary.loc['maxu', 'OP_Given'] = timeit(lambda: maxu(df), number=iterations)
summary.loc['andyhayden', 'OP_Given'] = timeit(lambda: andyhayden(df), number=iterations)


df = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(lowercase), (10000, 3))).sum(1),
    columns=['dialogue'])
df['episode'] = 1

summary.loc['pirsquared', '10000_3_letters'] = timeit(lambda: pirsquared(df), number=iterations)
summary.loc['maxu', '10000_3_letters'] = timeit(lambda: maxu(df), number=iterations)
summary.loc['andyhayden', '10000_3_letters'] = timeit(lambda: andyhayden(df), number=iterations)


summary
```

[image]