# How to implement Pandas GroupBy filter on mixed type data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Thanks for reading. Apologies for what I am sure is a simple problem to answer.

I have some dataframe:

```
df:
    Entry    Found
0    Dog      [1,0]
1    Sheep    [0,1]
2    Cow      "No Match"
3    Goat     "No Match"
```

I want to return a new dataframe which contains only entries which contain `No Match` in the `Found` column (and preserve their index order) i.e.:

Output:

```
    Entry    Found
0    Cow      "No Match"
1    Goat     "No Match"
```

I know to do this I must use the built in Pandas `GroupBy()` and `filter()` functions. Following these questions ([Filter data with groupby in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544301/filter-data-with-groupby-in-pandas)) and ([Pandas: DataFrame filtering using groupby and a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950835/pandas-dataframe-filtering-using-groupby-and-a-function)) I tried:

```
>> df.groupby('Found','Entry').filter(lambda x: type(x) == str)
>> No axis named Entry for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

and:

```
>> df.groupby('Found').filter(lambda x: type(x) == str)
>> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You could just filter the df prior to grouping: `df[df['Found'] == 'No Match']`, if that doesn't work you need to really consider why you would want to store lists in a df in the first place as it's ill-suited for pandas

Comment: @EdChum I appreciate your candid response. I agree, storing a list was inadvisable (it was a messy work around for an earlier problem - another fix may be in order). Writing your  `df[df['Found'] == 'No match']` **did not** return me an empty dataframe. (Turns out it's actually `"No Match"`, not `"No match"`

Comment: @EdChum Man, That's exactly what I needed... If I were to write `new_df= df[df['Found'] == 'No Match']` would that return a brand new dataframe that I could independently work with, or would it be a copy where, were I change to the original df, df_new would also change?

Comment: @ebeneditos Thank you for your comment and answer.

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Comment: @EdChum, are you happy for me to accept the answer listed (it is exactly what you wrote, but posted after you)? If you wanted to post yours as an answer I will accept - but it is up to you? Either way, I am very appreciative of your help as always.

Comment: Sure, regarding whether this operation will give you a view or copy, it depends on what you do with the filtered df. If you call `.copy()` on the df then it is definitely a copy, if not then it should warn you if you try to say set some row values, additionally you should read this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy which helps clarify some scenarios

Comment: @EdChum Will take a look - thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `groupby` function, you can call the query such as:

```
df = df[df["Found"] == "No Match"]
```

Thus it will look for the column `Found` if there are `"No Match"`, which will be `False` when it is a list, instead of an error.